# Find repeated characters (standing apart)

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all substrings that refer to such pattern: some character + some character + first character.
Now I have this in Python 2.7:

```
T = "i was here"
m = re.findall(r"([a-z])[a-z](\1)", T)
print m
```

this gives:

```
[('e', 'e')]
```

Seems that I am very close to achieving my goal, but I can't figure out how can I get **'ere'** as result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put parentheses also around the middle character:

```
>>> m = re.findall(r"([a-z])([a-z])(\1)", T)
>>> m
[('e', 'r', 'e')]
>>> ''.join(m[0])
'ere'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
>>> m = re.findall(r"(([a-z])([a-z])(\2))", T)
>>> m
[('ere', 'e', 'r', 'e')]
>>> m[0][0]
'ere'
```

Comment: @MikhailV what don't you understand? The outer parentheses around everything create capture group #1. The first group inside - `([a-z])` - creates group #2, which is referenced later.